# html/css text box formatting

Tags: html, css

I have an problem with my textboxes in HTML. I made a combo box to open text boxes for the user to enter two dates: the start date and the end date. I need them to be one below the other, but they end up with this format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3to1.png)

The code that I used is:

```
                <!--Range time-->
                <div class="input-group FixDatasInput" ng-show="datasType == 'rangeDate'">
                    <!--Initial Date-->
                    <div>
                        <span style="width:56px;" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="IconFix glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"
                            aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                        <input class="InitialDayInput DateFix form-control" type="input" placeholder="Dia" ng-model="initialDayFilterText" 
                            ng-change="setFilterDataCompare()">
                        <input class="InitialMonthInput form-control" type="input" placeholder="/ Mês" ng-model="initialMonthFilterText" 
                            ng-change="setFilterDataCompare()">
                        <input class="InitialYearInput DateFix form-control" type="input" placeholder="/ Ano" 
                            ng-model="initialYearFilterText" ng-change="setFilterDataCompare()">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <!--Finish Date-->
                    <div>
                        <span style="width:56px;" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="IconFix glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"
                            aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                        <input class="FinishDayInput DateFix form-control" type="input" placeholder="Dia" ng-model="finishDayFilterText"
                            ng-change="setFilterDataCompare()">
                        <input class="FinishMonthInput  form-control" type="input" placeholder="/ Mês" ng-model="finishMonthFilterText"
                            ng-change="setFilterDataCompare()">
                        <input class="FinishYearInput DateFix  form-control" type="input" placeholder="/ Ano" 
                            ng-model="finishYearFilterText" ng-change="setFilterDataCompare()">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: insert your css, pls

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what your CCS looks like, but just looking at the HTML and the image, my guess is the combined width of your text boxes is greater than the remaining line width since you have a static width on the calendar icon.